# Azure Application Insights Memory Usage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

We have a site running as an Azure Website for Docker.
This site uses Application Insights to reports metrics.

Now to the issue at hand.
There are 3 different graphs in Azure, seemingly reporting the same thing.
But with completely different values.

This image is from the diagnostics page. and seems to indicate that the app consumes very little memory (which we see locally too)

[image]

This image is from the Service Plan itself:

[image]

This final image is from the Application insights dashboard:
[image]

All three images are for a 24h timespan. all images are from the same time.

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here?
why is one graph saying 6% and another 35-45% and yet another is all over the place.

I'm not quite sure what more context to provide here, if there is anything more I should provide, please let me know.

Comment: Can you make sure that the service plan and application insights only monitor the one site?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old but...

It seems you're seeing different graphs indeed:

The first one shows the memory of your apps only (process' memory consumption); the second one shows the memory consumption average of the plan, so it will add all native processes required by your app to run; while the third one shows the available memory average, hence the difference.

I hope this helps a bit to understand those graphs